# R: Sparse submatrix without reducing original matrix dimension

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, dimension, submatrix

From this data frame `df`

```
  group   from     to weight
1     1   Joey   Joey      1
2     1   Joey Deedee      1
3     1 Deedee   Joey      1
4     1 Deedee Deedee      1
5     2 Johnny Johnny      1
6     2 Johnny  Tommy      1
7     2  Tommy Johnny      1
8     2  Tommy  Tommy      1
```

which can be created like this

```
df <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), from =
structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Deedee",
"Joey", "Johnny", "Tommy"), class = "factor"), to = structure(c(2L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Deedee", "Joey", "Johnny",
"Tommy"), class = "factor"), weight = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L)), .Names = c("group", "from", "to", "weight"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

a sparse matrix `mat` can be obtained using the Matrix package

```
mat <- sparseMatrix(i = as.numeric(df$from), j = as.numeric(df$to), x =
df$weight, dimnames = list(levels(df$from), levels(df$to)))
```

which looks like this:

```
4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
       Deedee Joey Johnny Tommy
Deedee      1    1      .     .
Joey        1    1      .     .
Johnny      .    .      1     1
Tommy       .    .      1     1
```

.

**How can I create a sparse submatrix using** `df$group` **without reducing the original matrix dimension?**

The result is supposed to look like this:

```
4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
       Deedee Joey Johnny Tommy
Deedee      1    1      .     .
Joey        1    1      .     .
Johnny      .    .      .     .
Tommy       .    .      .     .
```

**First Idea**

If I subset the data frame and create the submatrix

```
df1 <- subset(df, group == 1)
mat1 <- sparseMatrix(i = as.numeric(df1 $from), j = as.numeric(df1 $to),
x = df1 $weight)
```

the result is a 2 x 2 sparse Matrix. This is not an option. Besides "losing two nodes," I would also have to filter the factor levels to be used as dimension names.

The trick may be to not lose factors when creating the matrix.

**Second Idea**

If I set `df$weight` to zero for the group I'm not interested in and create the submatrix

```
df2 <- df
df2[df2$group == 2, 4] <- 0
mat2 <- sparseMatrix(i = as.numeric(df2$from), j = as.numeric(df2$to), x
= df2$weight, dimnames = list(levels(df$from), levels(df$to)))
```

the matrix has the right dimension and I can easily carry along the factor levels as dimension names, but the matrix now contains zeros:

```
4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
       Deedee Joey Johnny Tommy
Deedee      1    1      .     .
Joey        1    1      .     .
Johnny      .    .      0     0
Tommy       .    .      0     0
```

This is also not an option because row normalization creates `NaN`s and I run into trouble when I transform the matrix into a graph and perform network analysis.

Here, the trick may be to remove the zeros from the sparse matrix? But how?

In any case, the solution must be as efficient as possible because the matrices get very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your first idea:

```
mat1 <- sparseMatrix(i = as.numeric(df1$from), j = as.numeric(df1$to),
                     x = df1$weight, 
                     dims = c(length(levels(df$from)), length(levels(df$to))), 
                     dimnames = list(levels(df$from), levels(df$to)))

#4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#       Deedee Joey Johnny Tommy
#Deedee      1    1      .     .
#Joey        1    1      .     .
#Johnny      .    .      .     .
#Tommy       .    .      .     .
```